Dockered Apache / httpd:latest does not start up
I am trying to run the containerized Apache httpd on a server
Here is my docker-compose.yml file
version: '3'
services:
  httpd:
    container_name: httpd
    image: httpd:latest
    network_mode: host

docker-compose up

gives this below:
Recreating httpd ... done
Attaching to httpd
httpd    | AH00557: httpd: apr_sockaddr_info_get() failed for blast.server.com
httpd    | AH00558: httpd: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.0.1. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
httpd    | AH00557: httpd: apr_sockaddr_info_get() failed for blast.server.com
httpd    | AH00558: httpd: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.0.1. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
httpd    | [Thu Oct 24 19:12:27.242433 2024] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 1:tid 1] AH00489: Apache/2.4.62 (Unix) configured -- resuming normal operations
httpd    | [Thu Oct 24 19:12:27.263452 2024] [core:notice] [pid 1:tid 1] AH00094: Command line: 'httpd -D FOREGROUND'
httpd    | [Thu Oct 24 19:12:27.243243 2024] [mpm_event:alert] [pid 9:tid 9] (1)Operation not permitted: AH00480: ap_thread_create: unable to create worker thread
httpd    | [Thu Oct 24 19:12:27.243243 2024] [mpm_event:alert] [pid 10:tid 10] (1)Operation not permitted: AH00480: ap_thread_create: unable to create worker thread
httpd    | [Thu Oct 24 19:12:27.243405 2024] [mpm_event:alert] [pid 11:tid 11] (1)Operation not permitted: AH00480: ap_thread_create: unable to create worker thread
httpd    | [Thu Oct 24 19:12:29.265647 2024] [mpm_event:alert] [pid 1:tid 1] AH02324: A resource shortage or other unrecoverable failure was encountered before any child process initialized successfully... httpd is exiting!
httpd exited with code 0

since it is exiting at pid 9, 10, ... does it mean my machine is configured to only have 8 pids /threads, and that the first 8 were created? What should I adjust in the conf files (and which file)? Would that be ThreadsPerChild ? First time running apache through docker, havent had this issue with live servers.

What's the config? How do you run docker? What command line is used for the container?

The config is the same how it comes in the image.
https://hub.docker.com/layers/library/httpd/latest/images/sha256-7fa508eeda1a92870329441e0cdeb372e21b81e1209746dc162867281889edb1?context=explore
I think the docker-compose call would be equal to docker run -d -net host httpd:latest  (or similar)

Do you use rootless docker?

no, i dont know, normal installation?
